# How do i combine two bytes from network order into a usual short?

Tags: c#

How do i combine two bytes from network order into a usual short ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
short value = (short) ((byte1 << 8) | byte2);
```

I can't remember network order off the top of my head, but if that's not right, just swap round `byte1` and `byte2` :)

Comment: about networks order, IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder (for others if they dont know ;D) Thanks :D

Comment: @aPoC: But that means getting the short in the "wrong" format to start with. If you've got two separate bytes and you know which one you want to be the most significant, just do it to start with :)

Answer (score 1):

```
IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(...))
```

Comment: HostToNetworkOrder, surely? (I doubt that it matters, admittedly.) That assumes that BitConverter uses the "host" order... if I had the separate bytes to start with, I'd just put them the "right" way round to start with.

Comment: The "right" way round to begin with is platform dependant. Your solution is good for one platform, but you should be manually checking BitConverter.IsLittleEndian otherwise. I'd agree it's a better solution, I was just going off existing standard libraries.